# Order by future event of a project ASC, followed by past events DESC

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Edit 2 // This works pretty well, but gives me duplicates and as many rows as I have events. I need the same number of rows as I have projects:

```
Project::select('projects.*')
->leftJoin('events', 'events.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
->orderByRaw('(start_datetime < NOW()),
(case when start_datetime > NOW() then start_datetime end) ASC,
(case when start_datetime < NOW() then start_datetime end) DESC')
->with('events')
->get(); // ->unique() at the end works, but isn't quite right
```

Database:

```
Project: id
Event: id, project_id, start_datetime
```

Project Model:

```
public function events(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Event::class);
}
```

Event Model:

```
public function project(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
}
```

OLD FROM HERE:

---

Edit // This code is giving me the grouping and order I need, but how can I make it with a `projects` collection instead of a `projects` array?

```php
$events = Event::with('project')
    ->orderByRaw('(start_datetime < NOW()),
    (case when start_datetime > NOW() then start_datetime end) ASC,
    (case when start_datetime < NOW() then start_datetime end) DESC')
    ->get();

$projects = [];
foreach ($events as $event) {
    $projects[$event->project_id]['project'] = $event->project;
    $projects[$event->project_id]['events'][] = $event;
}
```

...

A project can have one or several events. Every event has a start date and time. How can I order by project that has the next upcoming event ASC, followed by projects with past events DESC. And within each project also order by next upcoming event ASC, followed by events DESC. Mouthful.

This is what I have that is working great to sort the events within each project:

```php
// Project Model
public function events(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Event::class)
    ->orderByRaw('(start_datetime < NOW()),
    (case when start_datetime > NOW() then start_datetime end) ASC,
    (case when start_datetime < NOW() then start_datetime end) DESC');
}
```

Now I need to find out how I can sort the projects based on the same criteria.

I'd love to make it work with just eloquent if possible, but I'm starting to think that I need some joins or unions?

I tried something random like this with collections, but I'm kind of lost:

```php
$projects->with('events')->get()->sortBy(function ($sort) {
    return $sort->events->pluck('start_datetime')->first();
});
```

Here's an example of how I want it to look. Put on your seatbelts ;)

```
Project A (1st because it has the next upcoming event)
- Event 1 Start Date Today
- Event 2 Start Date in 2 days
- Event 3 Start Date Yesterday (latest past event of the project)
- Event 4 Start Date 2 days ago (oldest event of the project at the bottom)

Project B (2nd because it has the second next upcoming event)
- Event 5 Start Date Tomorrow
- Event 6 Start Date in 4 days
- Event 7 Start Date Yesterday

Project C (3rd because it doesn't have a future event, but has the latest past event)
- Event 8 Start Date Yesterday
- Event 9 Start Date 2 days ago

Project D (4th because it has the oldest event)
- Event 10 2 days ago
- Event 11 3 days ago
```

I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As eager loading uses separate queries so you need to use join for this:

```
  $projects->join('events as e','e.project_id','project.id')
   ->orderBy('e.start_datetime', 'asc')
   ->select('projects.*')  
   ->with('events')
  ->get();
```

`Select` is use just to avoid fetching anything from a joined table

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried this and when I have 3 projects in my db, this query gives me 6 projects with duplicate events. Do I need to use some grouping on project id or how do I make sure that the join doesn't double up the info?

Comment: Here's the generated query ```"select `projects`.* from `projects` inner join `events` as `e` on `e`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id` where `projects`.`deleted_at` is null order by `e`.`start_datetime` asc"```

Comment: Clarification, I have 4 projects (three with 1 event and one with 3 events) and the resulting collection contains 6 projects. So I get as many projects back as I have events. Is this the expected result? My goal is to have a collection of 4 projects with no duplicated events.

Comment: Adding `->unique()` seems to solve it, but that seems like kind of a dirty fix.

Comment: I added my code to the top of the original post. What do you think?

Comment: leftjoin will take every record from projects where it has event or not which will not be good @SeaBass

Comment: I tried join too and got duplicates anyway. I used leftjoin because I want projects even if there are no events. Any other suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Can I use groupBy()? I tried but got an aggregate error.

Comment: Then you have to check for query time, like seed some huge amount of data and run this query if it's working fine then you can go with if not and it's taking too much memory and time then we have to implement some other logic. @SeaBass

Comment: Thanks! There was a comment here where you said that the query in your example shouldn’t return duplicates, but I can’t find it anymore. Based on my new code at the top and change leftjoin to join, do you mean that it shouldn’t return duplicates? How can I make it to only return as many records as there are projects? Thank you!