# Sort collection similar to query with cases in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, sorting

How can I apply this ordering to a collection instead?

```
orderByRaw('(start_datetime < NOW()),
    (case when start_datetime > NOW() then start_datetime end) ASC,
    (case when start_datetime < NOW() then start_datetime end) DESC')
```

```
sortBy(function ($p) {
    return $p->events->pluck('start_datetime'); // Collection of Carbon datetimes, but what do I do from here?
});
```

Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order by future event of a project ASC, followed by past events DESC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71521905/order-by-future-event-of-a-project-asc-followed-by-past-events-desc)

Comment: No, and that's actually also my question that is still unanswered :) This question is specific for if that particular query can be re-created with Laravel sortBy().

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby

You can, but it's not pretty. Basically you can pass an array of conditions to sortBy, like

```php
// ORDER BY column1 ASC, column2 DESC
sortBy([['column1', 'asc'], ['column2', 'desc']])
```

For more complicated sorting, you can pass an array of closures instead. Using the `spaceship operator (<=>)` for comparison helps a lot.